# Element duplicates when append

Tags: javascript, jquery

At first, I'm trying to create a basic tcg in jQuery, Ajax and PHP.
The following fiddle is my try to append the card to empty places and change the data attribute value, but When I click in a card, it creates other "cards" and the value doesn't changes.
http://jsfiddle.net/bNB89/1/
The code I tried to use for data changing:

```
$(this).data('place', 'field');
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using `append` in a class, so the content is being created in every element containing that class. You should instead fetch for the first element with the class, append to it and then remove the class so it won't be selected again. I set up a fiddle demonstrating it http://jsfiddle.net/bNB89/2/

Answer (score 0):

You get other cards because there are multiple `.myslot` elements and each one will get a copy.
Use a selector that will give you one item to append to. e.g. `.myslot:empty:first`.
`.data()` does not change data attributes it uses its own internal mechanism to store the data. If you really want to change the attribute you can use `attr`.

http://jsfiddle.net/bNB89/3/